# How to add Dom element dynamically in angular7

Tags: angular7

I am using angular 7 and I need to add a Dom element dynamically through the code.

I know the way of doing it in JavaScript

```
var adiv = document.createElement('div');
                adiv.classList.add("redmark");
                adiv.style.position = "absolute";
                document.body.appendChild(adiv);
                adiv.innerHTML = '< img src="css/led_red.png" class="zoom" style="position: absolute;">';
                adiv.style.display = "";
                adiv.style.left = (position.x - 16) + 'px';
                adiv.style.top = (position.y - 32) + 'px';
                var markObj = { position: [x, y, z], mark: “as”}
```

But how to do it in angular?

Comment: What are the requirements? Do you want to show it when specific condition is true?

Comment: it will be shown when i click the button @Kenny